# Rotation of a camera at optical center

Tags: computer-vision

By rotating the pinhole camera at it's optical center, Just asking generally, can we get 3D informations? if yes, Can you explain or provide sources or terms so I can read it up?

Comment: You really need to be more specific. I would suggest writing about the camera setup, coordinate planes, what kind of math background you have, tools you have available etc.

Comment: I'm currently learning about stereo system, motion field and disparity

Comment: There are most likely tools here http://opencv.org/.  Reference documentation http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/refman.html.

Comment: I'm looking for theories and equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given only this rotation you can not get any 3D information. Even if there might be some disparity for the pixels close to the border, in real world situations this will most likely not work.

As a good reference I can point you to the book from [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision* from Hartley and Zisserman](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/).